# What does hg bookmark mean in this context?

Tags: git, mercurial

I am reading through [Chris's excellent article](http://chris.improbable.org/2010/07/15/how-work-git-and-push-changes-mercurial-using-hg-g/) about working with git and pushing to BitBucket. With the instructions presented there, I managed to get everything working. However, I would like to understand what happens there. I'm specifically interested in this line:

```
hg bookmark hg/default -r default
```

I understand that this creates a bookmark named `hg/default`, but why does it have `default` as a revision? What does this mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `-r` (or `--rev`) tells Mercurial that the bookmark should be set to the head of the `default` branch.

Using this technique, you set a bookmark to a revision other than that of your working copy.

This is documented in [`hg help bookmark`](http://selenic.com/hg/help/bookmarks).

Comment: Ah, I see. If I wouldn't have used the `-r` switch, then the bookmark would have "started" at my current revision, right?

Comment: I *think* it would have used the current branch and the current change set on that branch

Comment: @Geo: You are correct, if no `-r` is given, then the `bookmark` is set to your working copy revision.

Answer (score 0):

If no branch name is set manually, Mercurial assigns the branch name `default`.

`default` is the name of a particular path of changes (change sets) and in this case it is used to create your bookmark.